# How can i save and get images in html5 websql database?

Tags: image, html

Any one can please help me out how to save and get an image in html5 websql database.

Comment: Did you manage to get it working?

Comment: i used following file api to read image to store and get from sqldb       http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/

Answer (score 0):

Create a [data URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) to store and load your images.

See the following [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/934012/get-image-data-in-javascript) that explains how to extract a data URI.